# Why isn't a transformer a short circuit?

Tags: transformer, short-circuit, theory

I'm a newbie with electronic components and I never fully understood why [transformers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformer), while essentially being a short-circuit from a wire perspective, don't act like short circuits (i.e. they don't just blindly behave like a waterfall of electrons).

Why is that and how is it related to the "load" attached to the transformer itself?
I'd prefer a 'layman's terms' explanation but I don't mind some math if necessary.

Comment: Because inductance!

Comment: Put DC on it, and watch the smoke of your long wire short circuit.

Comment: @PlasmaHH What? You need short the output/input and bring the input to nominal current to find 
characteristic of a transformer.....

Comment: @MathieuL: Did I ever say that I gave instructions on how to find characteristics of a transformer? All I gave was an instruction on how to see a transformer behave as a short.

Comment: Are these instructions speak of DC?

Comment: @PlasmaHH Most of DC source will burn before the transformer... Little transfo can handle like 10 amps...

Comment: @MathieuL: most of my dc sources will be totally fine and go into current limit mode, a few will foldback.

Comment: @PlasmaHH Last semester, a lab assistant destroy a D.C. source when he put 20 V on a shorted transfo, the source literally burned. But it depends, of the DC source and the transfo, a little transfo on a breadboard will die if you short it, but a 1 kVA transfo can handle your common 3 A D.C. source of electronics.

Comment: @MathieuL: sure, if you have bad power supplies they break, but if you work in the EE field you should know about these things and use good ones instead.

Comment: @PlasmaHH Public university, and we are going under budget compression :P

Comment: You might wonder as well why capacitors are not open circuits...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As transformers are usually used with AC rather than with DC, there is what is known as *[inductance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductance)* \$L\$, which is a property of a conductor to "resist" the changes in the current flowing in it due to the magnetic fields induced by that current (self-inductance).

The magnetic field is "resisting" due to the fact that the alternating magnetic field is in turn trying to induce current in the opposite direction. So when we speak of AC, it is an alternating current, i.e. constantly changing which will be resisted by such a conductor.

The amount of magnetic field created by a conductor is relative to the density of the conductor windings, so a coil with many windings will create a stronger magnetic field, which in turn will resist more to the changes.

In case of transformer, there is an additional coil "sharing" the magnetic field with the primary one, so the magnetic field is trying to induce a current in this secondary coil as well. But when it is open, or connected to a load, it is "hard" to induce much current there, so it is "resisting" harder in the primary coil as well. This is pretty much of the intuitive understanding. If you want some math, you can easily find it.

Comment: Interesting, any intuitive way to visualize this?

Comment: @user3834459 A flywheel is the usual analogy for an inductor. As long as a shaft keeps rotating at a constant speed, a flywheel doesn't have any effect on how much work it takes to keep it turning (at least, if you assume it's frictionless). But as soon as you try to speed up or slow down the shaft, the flywheel does its best to counteract that. And if you try to wugga-wugga-wugga the shaft back and forth (which is AC), the flywheel will make that difficult in proportion to the frequency. The analogy doesn't extend well to transformers, though.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is reactance, which is a form of impedance, and is measured in ohms, which is also the unit of measurement for resistance.  It is directly related to inductance and frequency: 2·π·f·L (f=frequency of voltage, L=inductance). As frequency and/or inductance increases, the reactance of the coil increases.   If you think of reactance as resistance (though it technically isn't) you will see that an increase in reactance will result in a lower current (Ohm's law: I = V/R).

For example, DC will have a frequency of 0, which will produce a reactance of 0, which will basically be a short circuit with only the resistance of the wire to limit the overall current.  Inductance alone only limits the current's rate of change, it is the combination of inductance with frequency that limits maximum current of the primary winding of a transformer with an open secondary.  Note also that an AC voltage source with a frequency of 1 Hz will behave similarly to DC though the inductance remains the same.

More turns of wire equals more inductance which equals more reactance resulting in less current (as long as frequency is not zero.) Higher frequency does the same.

Comment: Resistance and reactance are forms of impedance: impedance is Z, resistance is R, and reactance is X: Z = R + jX. The difference is reactance can return its energy to the source, drawing no net power by itself; resistance is always dissipative.

Comment: 10-4, I was trying to convey the idea in 'layman's terms' as the OP requested and felt that the question had not been answered adequately.  Thank you for pointing this out, I can see that my explanation is misleading.  I'll adjust the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Any current that changes with time creates a self-opposing electric field. Inductors and transformers are just highly concentrated forms of this phenomenon. We concentrate, then magnify, this effect in a small space - for convenience.

We concentrate it by winding the wire many times over again in a small space; and we often choose to magnify it by using a material with high permeability (a material like iron, which I'm sure you know is "magnetic" or "ferromagnetic").  The end result is an electrical component in our circuit that "resists" the current being passed through it.

That's a very high level explanation.

Answer (score -1):

Transformer don't act as short because they aren't perfect. In a nutshell:

First, the wire that are used cause Copper Loss, because of Joule Heating in wire.

Secondly, the material that are used in the metal struct that link both set of wire doesn't have an infinite permeability, therefore, some magnetic lines leak from the struct therefore affecting the transformer efficiency.

Finally, there is the mutual inductance effect that is cause by each bobine on the other one. Practically, this effect is neglect most of the time because the Mutual inductance got a massive value compare to the two other effect.

You can model these effects by using the [Real model - Equivalent circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformer#/media/File:TREQCCT.jpg).

Comment: The copper loss is not really any different from an other piece of wire which we would still call a short circuit. The key reason in the inductance and coupling with the secondary.

Comment: @TomCarpenter Check my link, coupling with the secondary is modal by X_M coupling inductance and R_M is the Iron loss, these value are a lot higher than the value X_p/R_p (self/copper loss from primary) and X_s/R_s (self/copper loss from secondary) that are under 10 ohms most of the time. The effect of mutual can be neglected in most case.

Answer (score -3):

In very short reluctance. Long time ago I read while in polytechnic.
Current passes through coil produces flux than produces reverse current from first one so it is zero charge at junction then.....

Comment: Reluctance does the opposite. It hinders inductance and inductance is what hinders AC current. So a high-reluctance core configuration would actually cause a high short-circuit current. Welcome to EE.SE

Answer (score -5):

I think what he is asking is why when two different phases touch they short but when two phases are connected to a transformer together they do not. It is because the coils create resistance which like your load determines current; if the primary coils become shorted to themselves then the primary will short out.

Comment: The answer accepted six months ago is worth reading as it explains the theory correctly. (Your's doesn't.) Welcome to EE.SE.